# Strahler stream order

Tags: qgis, strahler

I have a layer of line objects representing stream channels. These have been generated at 50K scale but do not have a Strahler order designation. The tutorials I've seen using the SAGA extension in QGIS all start at converting a DEM. I don't need this step. Is it possible to produce Strahler order on a vector layer of connected lines?

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I wrote a QGIS plugin named [Strahler](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QGISStrahler-master/) which achieves precisely what you're looking for. Unfortunately it is only compatible with QGIS 2.* because I stopped its maintenance. It might be useful for you though.

Comment: Is there anything that would induce you to update your plugin to work with 3.x? I loved your work with 2.18, but I don't have that installed at work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the SAGA GIS order strahler module? I have tried it and it seems efficient, but it does not generate the vectorial layer

Answer (score 0):

you have probably already solved this problem, but I will leave a link here in case colleagues with a similar problem come across this discussion

There is a plugin for QGIS, which allows you to calculate attributes on a vector layer - lines ranking https://linesranking.readthedocs.io/en/latest/